# Why is $\mathbb{Q}(\operatorname{exp}(\frac{2\pi i}{5}))$ a field extension of degree four not five?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $\zeta = \operatorname{exp}(\frac{2\pi i}{5})$. Now, consider $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. The minimal polynomial is $P=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$, therefore the extension is of degree $4$. But why? As $\zeta$ is a root of $P$, $\{1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\zeta^3\}$ must be a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-Vector space. But where are the linear combinations with $\zeta^4$?

Comment: $\zeta^4 = -\zeta^3 -\zeta^2 - \zeta - 1$

Comment: Given that @badjohn gave a really good answer in his hint, it feels improper to post an answer myself. However I would encourage you to post an answer to your own question from what you have learned. That way we can resolve this post.

Comment: @KenDuna I guess that was quite a heavy hint.  Too much?

Comment: @badjohn No, I think it was a great hint.

Comment: I am not sure, yet, on how to find which exponentiations of n-th roots of unity are linear combinations of the others. In retrospect, the case above was obvious, but what about the case $X^6-1$. The minimal polynomial for the 6-th root of unity is of degree 2, that is $\{1,\zeta_6\}$ must be a $\mathbb{Q}$-Basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6)$. Now, how can I determine the linear combinations? (I know that $X^6-1=(X-1)(X+1)(X^2+X+1)(X^2-X+1)$)

Comment: Those are [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: Yes, should I just remultiply them back again, in an iterative manner, to get all the $X^k$ I need? Will I run in any "holes"?

Comment: Why multiply anything? The n'th cyclotomic polynomial is the minimal polynomial you were after.

Comment: No, I want linear combinations $a+b\zeta_6$, $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, of all exponentiations $\zeta_6^k$.

Comment: You can determine powers of $\zeta_6$ as linear combinations of $1$ and $\zeta_6$ using geometry - draw a hexagon.

Comment: You need to understand that in general the $n$th roots of unity satisfy the equation $x^{n} - 1 = 0$ but this has a factor $(x - 1)$ so that the degree of a cyclotomic field ($\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$) must be less than $n$. It can be proved with some effort that if $\zeta_{n}$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$ is of degree $\phi(n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: That, I understand. I had difficulties finding linear combinations resulting in the other n-th roots that are not part of the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degree of this field is the degree of the minimum polynomial of $\zeta$.
We certainly know that $x^5-1$ is a polynomial that $\zeta$ satisfies, but it is **not irreducible**, therefore not minimal.
This is so because $x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ (that's where badjone's hint came from - I felt like I needed to explain that).

There's a reasult that says that $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+... + x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence the minimum polynomial is $ x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general question you are asking is, for an algebraic element$~\zeta$ for which a minimal polynomial$~P$ (over a base field$~F$ that is $\Bbb Q$ here) is known, how to write a power $\zeta^k$ with $k\geq d=\deg P$ as $F$-linear combination of $1,\zeta,\ldots,\zeta^{d-1}$. This can be generalised to any polynomial $A[\zeta]$ of $\zeta$ instead of $\zeta^k=X^k[\zeta]$. The answer is simply to perform Euclidian division of $A$ by$~P$, retaining only the remainder$~R$ of the division; then $Q[\zeta]=R[\zeta]$ gives your $F$-linear combination.

In the example of the question $P=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ and $Q=X^4$; the division gives $A=QP+R$ with quotient $Q=1$ and remainder $R=-X^3-X^2-X-1$, so $\zeta^4=-1-\zeta-\zeta^2-\zeta^3$ is the expression you are after. Another example for primitive $12$-th roots of unity and $k=11$ you get for $P$ the cycloctomic polynomial $P=X^4-X^2+1$, and the division gives $X^{11}=QP+R$ with $Q=X^7+X^5-X$ and $R=-X^3+X$, so $\zeta^{11}=\zeta-\zeta^3$ in this case.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.